# Bootstrap navbar - Grayscale theme

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am looking at this [bootstrap theme](http://startbootstrap.com/templates/grayscale/)

I would like to know how to make the navbar style black all the time (like how it is when you scroll or jump to a section).

I am a css + bootstrap newbie and the amount of css navbar manipulation going on has confused me so I don't know which class I should edit to make this work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this to your CSS file:

```
nav.navbar {
    background: #000;
}
```

that's it!

Answer (score 0):

Its nothing but Inverted navbar

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
  ...
</nav>
```

**[REFERENCE](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-inverted)**